# How to enable check of particular file in pytest configuration?

Tags: python, pytest, setup.py, pylint, flake8

My `setup.cfg` file looks like this

```
[bdist_wheel]
universal=1
[aliases]
test=pytest
[tool:pytest]
addopts=-s tests app -vv --cov app --cov-report html --pylint --flake8 --doctest-modules -ra --no-print-logs
```

I want my `setup.py` file to be checked too, but it's located in the root of my project. I don't want to add the root and ignore each folder that doesn't need to be checked.

How to add check of `setup.py` file? Being more specific, I want `flake8` and `pylint` to check it.